# apache-poi 4.0 NullPointer for series setTitle

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData$Series.setTitle(XDDFChartData.java:122)

The code follows as below:

```
CellReference cellref = new CellReference("A6"); 

//A6 value = "My Title"

XDDFLineChartData.Series series3 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series)data.addSeries(xs, ys3);
series3.setMarkerSize((short) 6);
series3.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.DIAMOND);

series3.setTitle("My Title",cellref);
```

I checked the documentation, it required a string for `arg0` and a `CellReference` for `arg1`.

I keep ending up with a `NullPointerException`. Am I missing something??

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: The new `XDDF` stuff seems far away from being useable until now. in [XDDFChartData.Series.setTitle](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_0_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartData.java?view=markup#l117) `getSeriesText()` is used without `null` check. But [XDDFLineChartData.Series.getSeriesText](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_0_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFLineChartData.java?view=markup#l90) of course may return `null` since `series.getTx()` may return `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question how to repair the bug in `XDDFChartData.Series.setTitle`:

In [XDDFChartData.Series.setTitle](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_0_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartData.java?view=markup#l117) `getSeriesText()` is used without null check. But [XDDFLineChartData.Series.getSeriesText()](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_0_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFLineChartData.java?view=markup#l90) of course may return null since `series.getTx()` may return null. So we need make sure, that there is a series text element already before using `XDDFChartData.Series.setTitle`.

```
...
XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
...
XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
...
XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
data.addSeries(...);
data.addSeries(...);
chart.plot(data);

if (chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getTx() == null) 
 chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewTx();
data.getSeries().get(0).setTitle("Series 1 Title", null);

if (chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(1).getTx() == null)
 chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(1).addNewTx();
data.getSeries().get(1).setTitle("Series 2 Title", null);
...
//setting the axis Ids to the LineChart
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(bottomAxis.getId());
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(leftAxis.getId());
...
```